# Show that loop in $S^1$ is not nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $q$ be the covering map $z\mapsto z^2$ from $S^1$ into itself. Let $\alpha$ be a path in $S^1$ from a point $x$ to its antipodal. I need to show that the  path $q\circ \alpha$ is not null homotopic, i.e. here is not homotopic with a constant function. I can see how this path should “wrap” the circle around, but I can not argue this formally.

Comment: @Sumanta why does it wrap around the circle only once? This is not true based on what op has included in the post.

Comment: Jerry, have you considered lifting $\alpha:I\rightarrow S^1$ through the universal covering $\exp:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$? The point is that the map $q$ is covered by the map $\times 2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.